# Ubuntu freezes frequently giving error : GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kernel, freeze

My computer freezes allmost every day. Sometimes just Compiz crashes when I try to open Unity menu. Very often screen just freezes completely and doesn't respond anything. Then I have to restart X. Every time I put my computer standby mode or wake it up I get following error:

```
kernel: [  271.043895] [drm:gen6_sanitize_pm] *ERROR* Power management discrepancy: GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS expected 16000000, was 12060000
```

I tried to google the error and I found that updating kernel would help. I tried to install suggested  `kernel 3.6` and also `kernel 3.4`. With both kernels standy mode doesn't work at all so I had to switch back to `3.2.0-53-generic`. My OS is Ubuntu `12.04 LTS`

How could I fix this very anoying problem?

Here is asked information:

```
tapio@Aspire-3830T:~$ sudo lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

tapio@Aspire-3830T:~$ sudo uname -a
Linux Aspire-3830T 3.2.0-53-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 21:01:03 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

tapio@Aspire-3830T:~$ sudo lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
tapio@Aspire-3830T:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel     2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1                               X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

Comment: It seems your graphics problem, The current kernel you are using is not matching with graphics driver you have installed. I want you to paste these commands results by editing your question: `sudo lspci | grep VGA`, `sudo uname -a` and `sudo lsb_release -a`. Reply..

Comment: I've added information you asked.

Comment: Since you are using `Ubuntu 12.4.3` I suggest you to use `Kernel 3.8.0.30` and the `xserver-xorg` drivers for `lts-raring` version. In order to proceed, I want the output of one more command: `sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel`. To get the information of this command is important. Reply..

Comment: Ok. I added that too.

Comment: Ok, it seems that you are using an ancient `Kernel 3.2.x` and `Old graphics driver`. You could solve your problem, but I expect from you to follow them very precisely, and also it is little lengthy. I've solved my issue and I suggested to someone he too solved it. So I recommend you to do it if you've tried all and nothing helped you, and you are willing to give it a try..

Comment: Check my answer.. Reply if you need further assistance..

Comment: thanks a lot for providing this tutorial. I fillowed it and updated successfuly kernel to 3.8.0.39. However, now my chrome and firefox crash whenever I play a video there. Any advise?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps precisely!

1. Run following command in terminal and `tick` all check boxes under <kbd>Ubuntu Software</kbd> and <kbd>Updates</kbd> tabs. If already ticked then leave it.

   ```
   sudo software-properties-gtk
   ```

   then update your repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install `Linux Kernel 3.8.0` by selecting following packages in `Synaptic`:

   ```
   linux-generic-lts-raring
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30
   linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
   linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic
   linux-image-generic-lts-raring
   ```

   you can also install `Kernel 3.8.x` by executing following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-3.8.0-30 linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic linux-image-generic-lts-raring
   ```

   Once installed execute following command to update-grub and reboot your system(be sure to select `Kernel 3.8.0.30` from your grub menu):

   ```
   sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
   ```

   Before trying to *3rd* step I just want you to try *4th* step. If it fixes your problem then no need to install latest `Xserver-Xorg` packages so you can skip *3rd* step.
3. Install all `-lts-raring` packages for `Xserver-Xorg` using following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring libxatracker1-lts-raring xserver-xorg-core-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-raring libxrandr-ltsq2 x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring xserver-common-lts-raring
   ```

   Why this list is so long because I ensure that you install all `lts-raring` packages for `xserver-xorg`. I recommend you to copy and paste it in terminal. It will remove already installed Xserver-Xorg packages which was meant for previous kernel. so press `y` when it prompts to remove such packages.. Run this command to ensure you installed all:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-raring
   ```

   restart your system.
4. Now execute following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
   ```

   If last step shows some error, then execute these commands `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get --purge remove`, `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`.

   Then again try to run the command that gives you error. If still it gives you the same error then replace that command with this one: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep 'lts-raring' | tr '\n' ' ')`.

   Then continue to next:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   Then restart your system again:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. After reboot your system should work great.

**A short description of all steps mentioned above:**

*1st* Step ensures that you'll able to download `lts-raring` packages.

In *2nd* step you are installing a good stable kernel for your system, you are using so old kernel: `3.2.x`.

*3rd* Step will install `Xserver-Xorg` packages including `graphics card driver` which is best supported by `Kernel 3.8.0`

*4th* Step is used to re-configure the packages installed in your system to latest kernel just you installed.

It is not that much tough, I did it without any problem. And my system works great now! If you get any problem or error at any particular step, just reply mentioning that command with the error. I'll be waiting for your reply..

Comment: Now I don't get error message anymore and also standby-mode works. I'm not sure about crashes yet but I'll answer if it this crashes again. Thank you!